# iOS, Animating view's constraints causes error "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints"

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am attemptin to animate one of my container view's constraints. In IB, the the view is constrained fine without errors or warnings. When I call these methods in viewDidLoad, to change the views y coordinate like so:

```
 self.queueContainerYConst.constant += 550;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

I get the message for "unable to satisfy constraints...". While running the app, my animations and UI look fine, everything is appears to be constrained properly. Here is the entire message I get in the console.

```
2015-05-03 14:17:52.668 Streamacy[15914:3333195] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x155a95c0 V:|-(614)-[UIView:0x155a83a0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x155a91b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x155a95f0 V:[UIView:0x155a83a0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x155a91b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x155af080 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x155a91b0(568)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x155a95f0 V:[UIView:0x155a83a0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x155a91b0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-05-03 14:17:52.684 Streamacy[15914:3333195] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1566a2a0 UIView:0x156a1900.width == UIView:0x156a1900.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x156a9000 V:[UIView:0x156a1900]-(32)-[UIProgressView:0x15688f30]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x156a0df0 V:[UIProgressView:0x15688f30]-(11)-[MarqueeLabel:0x156a7360'Awake']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x156a0eb0 UIView:0x1569dd90.trailingMargin == UIView:0x156a1900.trailing + 99>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x156a0f10 UIView:0x156a1900.leading == UIView:0x1569dd90.leadingMargin + 99>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x156a0f40 UIView:0x156a1900.top == UIView:0x1569dd90.topMargin - 46>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x156a92f0 V:[UILabel:0x156a6ea0'Tycho']-(17)-[UITableView:0x1587a000]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x156a93b0 V:[MarqueeLabel:0x156a7360'Awake']-(2)-[UILabel:0x156a6ea0'Tycho']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x156a94d0 V:[UITableView:0x1587a000]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x156a8b20]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x156a4cf0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x156a8b20(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x156a4810 _UILayoutGuide:0x156a8b20.bottom == UIView:0x1569dd90.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x156b6070 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x1569dd90(320)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x156b60a0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x1569dd90(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1566a2a0 UIView:0x156a1900.width == UIView:0x156a1900.height>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-05-03 14:17:52.688 Streamacy[15914:3333195] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x156a9000 V:[UIView:0x156a1900]-(32)-[UIProgressView:0x15688f30]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x156a0df0 V:[UIProgressView:0x15688f30]-(11)-[MarqueeLabel:0x156a7360'Awake']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x156a0f40 UIView:0x156a1900.top == UIView:0x1569dd90.topMargin - 46>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x156a92f0 V:[UILabel:0x156a6ea0'Tycho']-(17)-[UITableView:0x1587a000]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x156a93b0 V:[MarqueeLabel:0x156a7360'Awake']-(2)-[UILabel:0x156a6ea0'Tycho']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x156a94d0 V:[UITableView:0x1587a000]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x156a8b20]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x156a4cf0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x156a8b20(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x156a4810 _UILayoutGuide:0x156a8b20.bottom == UIView:0x1569dd90.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x156b60a0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x1569dd90(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x156a9000 V:[UIView:0x156a1900]-(32)-[UIProgressView:0x15688f30]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

It appears that everything inside my container view gets misplaced, why?. Am I animating/changing my view improperly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're view is over constrained. You have a constraint of 614 to the top and 0 to the bottom of its superview, but the height of that view is 568, so those numbers don't add up. It would be better to only have one of those vertical constraints and a fixed hight for your view if that works for your purposes (that "fixed" height could be made relative to the superview's height if you ned it to adjust for different screen sizes).

Comment: Yes this is right, thank you. How can I make the view's height relative to the super view? Can I do that in IB?

Comment: @Andy Yes, you can do that in IB. Select the view and its superview, then choose "Equal Heights" from the pin menu. Then edit that constraint to change the multiplier value from 1 to whatever fraction you want.